# TableView comes up empty after implementing GCD

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to incorporate grand central dispatch in my table view. I have a property: `NSArray *topPlaces`

`topPlaces` is is an array of dictionaries from a Flickr query. This takes a bit of time to perform and so I want to put it on a separate thread. This table uses `topPlaces` to fill out each row of the table (note: this table is the first view to appear when the application is loaded). Because a few methods call getTopPlaces, I do a lazy instantiation in getTopPlaces in the event that topPlaces is not initialized. My code currently:

```
- (NSArray *)getTopPlaces
{

   if (!_topPlaces)
      {
        dispatch_queue_t downloadrQueue = dispatch_queue_create("lister downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadrQueue, ^{
            _topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_content" ascending:YES];

                NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
                NSArray *flickrTopPlacesAlphabetic = [_topPlaces sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

                _topPlaces = flickrTopPlacesAlphabetic;
            });
        });
        dispatch_release(downloadrQueue);
      }

   return _topPlaces;
}
```

The main problem I'm trying to solve is that when a row is selected, it segues to a new table view. But when I select a row, it freezes for a few seconds until the new table loads. I want the user to be able to scroll even while the row is selected and preparing to segue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this slightly more efficiently as [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740597/jacob-jennings) suggested you would do something like this (replace your_table_view_object with a ref to the actual object):

```
- (void)updateTopPlaces
{

   if (!_topPlaces)
      {
        dispatch_queue_t downloadrQueue = dispatch_queue_create("lister downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadrQueue, ^{
            _topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];


            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"_content" ascending:YES];

            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
            NSArray *flickrTopPlacesAlphabetic = [_topPlaces sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            _topPlaces = flickrTopPlacesAlphabetic;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [your_table_view_object reloadData];
            });
        });
        dispatch_release(downloadrQueue);
      }
}
```

To finish off his suggestions you would make an instance variable of type dispatch_queue_t and remove the creation and release of the dispatch queue from this function. For more specific help on this we would need to see the entire class implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this example project helpful: https://github.com/akosma/async-uitableview/

Comment: If you have additional information related to the question, try editing the question instead of answering it next time :)

Comment: I don't have the rep to do that yet. But thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

First, naming methods starting with get goes against [Apple's coding guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html).  There's a rare and specific case for naming methods starting with get.

Your primary issue is that you're dispatching a task asynchronously to populate _topPlaces and returning it before the asynchronous call populates it.  You could replace it with dispatch_sync, but then you would lose any performance gain of processing on a GCD background queue.  Instead, try this:

1. Do not return anything from this method (void)
2. Move your sorting up a level into the downloadrQueue block (no need to jump back to the main thread yet - sorting is costly)
3. In your main queue block, call reloadData on your table view
4. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, populate your table based on topPlaces

Your second issue is that you're creating and destroying a queue when you should be holding on to it.  Trying storing the downloadrQueue as a property and keeping it for the lifetime of your table's view controller.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob. I'm confused about a few things. For 1. I don't see how I could make a getter method for an NSArray property return nothing. I'm also wondering how to store downloadrQueue as a property (what type would it be?) and why this is necessary.